# No access to this from within nested callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code:

```
var Company = function(app) {
    this.crypto = require('ezcrypto').Crypto;
    var Company = require('../models/company.js');
    this.company = new Company(app);
}

// Create the company
Company.prototype.create = function (name, contact, email, password, callback) {
        this.hashPassword(password, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(this.company); // Undefined
            this.company.create(name, contact, email, result.password, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    return callback(err);
                }
                return callback(null, result);
            });
        });
}

// Get company with just their email address
Company.prototype.hashPassword = function (password, callback) {
    if(typeof password !== 'string') {
        var err = 'Not a string.'
    } else {
        var result = {
            password: this.crypto.SHA256(password)
        };
    }

    if (err) {
        return callback(err);
    }
    return callback(null, result);
}
module.exports = Company;
```

The problem is that `this.company` is undefined on line 11 of that code block.

I know `this` is not what I think, but I'm not sure how to refactor to get access to the correct `this`.

Comment: your hashPassword function is not asynchronous -.-

Comment: @Raynos What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should be returning the result or error. There is no need to use a callback, your allowed to return values from methods

Comment: @Raynos Really? I thought I had to use callbacks for this to be non-blocking? Or am I simply retarded?

Comment: Your simply retarded, callbacks don't make it non blocking. Doing async IO makes it non blocking. take a look at `hashpassword` your doing blocking stuff then calling the callback in a blocking fashion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

so theres 2 solution's to this

first the dirty one

```
Company.prototype.create = function (name, contact, email, password, callback) {
    var that = this; // just capture this in the clojure <-
    this.hashPassword(password, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(that.company); // Undefined
        that.company.create(name, contact, email, result.password, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }
            return callback(null, result);
        });
    });
 }
```

and the clean one using bind https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

```
 Company.prototype.create = function (name, contact, email, password, callback) {
    this.hashPassword(password, (function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(this.company); // Undefined
        this.company.create(name, contact, email, result.password, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }
            return callback(null, result);
        });
    }).bind(this));
 }
```

Comment: just a subjective preference use the one you like most.

Comment: @megakorre they are both dirty :(

Comment: @Raynos what would you do instead?

Comment: @JoshSmith I would rage about how inner functions don't have their `this` value default to the `this` value of the outer function and use of the two dirty solutions. Alternatively you can use `.bindAll` patterns on instances. (see underscore.bindAll)

Answer (score 1):

You can reference `this` through another variable by declaring it in the `Company.create` scope, like this:

```
// Create the company
Company.prototype.create = function (name, contact, email, password, callback) {
        var me = this;
        this.hashPassword(password, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(me.company); // Undefined - not anymore
            me.company.create(name, contact, email, result.password, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    return callback(err);
                }
                return callback(null, result);
            });
        });
}
```

Untested, but it should work like this.